# updating a table in bookshelf.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am trying to updated a status field in my table using this mysql query:

`UPDATE battles SET status = "FINISHED" WHERE status like "LIVE" AND end_date < NOW();`

However I am using bookshelf.js and can't seem to make it work. That's how it looks like:

```
return this.Model.collection().query(qb => qb.where('status', 'LIKE', status).andWhere('end_date', '<', connection.knex.fn.now())).set({ status: 'FINISHED' });
```

Could you guys tell me what I am doing wrong or how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You are using **set** method to update the column of the table. But Check the [official docs](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-set), **set** method is used to update the collection of models.
 Example:

`var vanHalen = new bookshelf.Collection([eddie, alex, stone, roth]);
 vanHalen.set([eddie, alex, stone, hagar]);`

You can use the following structure

```
 CollectionModel.forge().query({where: {status: "LIVE"}}).fetch().then(function (resData) {
    _.each(resData.models, function (model) { //I am looping over models using underscore, you can use any loop
         model.save({ status: 'FINISHED' }, {method: 'update'}, {patch: true})
              .then(function(row) {
                  console.log("row updated");  
               })

    })

})
```